# Scale picture using LWJGL 3 and modern OpenGL in an SWT context

Tags: java, opengl, swt, computer-vision, lwjgl

I'm hoping to scale 12MP images from a machine vision camera using [LWJGL 3](http://www.lwjgl.org/) and an SWT GLCanvas.

Scaling is obviously computationally intensive so I'd like to get the GPU to take care of this for me, but I am very unfamiliar with OpenGL. Further, every example I've looked at for LWJGL appears to be for much older versions of LWJGL or use deprecated methods; it appears LWJGL has undergone radical changes throughout its life.

I've provided a sample class which should describe how I'm desiring to implement this functionality, but I need help filling in the blanks (preferably using modern OpenGL and LWJGL 3):

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.opengl.GLCanvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.opengl.GLData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext;

public class LiveCameraView extends Composite
{
  private GLCanvas canvas;

  public LiveCameraView(Composite parent, int style)
  {
    super(parent, style);
    this.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    GLData data = new GLData();
    data.doubleBuffer = true;

    canvas = new GLCanvas(this, SWT.NONE, data);
  }

  public void updateImage(byte[] bgrPixels, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
  {
    canvas.setCurrent();
    GLContext.createFromCurrent();

    /*
     * STEP 1: Translate pixels into a GL texture from the 3-byte BGR byte[]
     * buffer.
     */

    /*
     * STEP 2: Now that the GPU has the full sized image, we'll get the GPU to
     * scale the image appropriately.
     */
    double scalingFactor = getScalingFactor(imageWidth, imageHeight);

    canvas.swapBuffers();
  }

  private double getScalingFactor(int originalWidth, int originalHeight)
  {
    int availableWidth = canvas.getBounds().width;
    int availableHeight = canvas.getBounds().height;

    // We can either scale to the available width or the available height, but
    // in order to guarantee that the whole image is visible we choose the
    // smaller of the two scaling factors.
    double scaleWidth = (double) availableWidth / (double) originalWidth;
    double scaleHeight = (double) availableHeight / (double) originalHeight;
    double scale = Math.min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    return scale;
  }

}
```

In a separate thread new images are being acquired from the camera continuously. Ideally that thread will asynchronously invoke the `updateImage(...)` method and provide the raw BGR data of the most recent image.

I believe this should be achievable using the outlined paradigm, but I could be way off base. I appreciate any good direction.

As a final note, this question arose from my initial question asked here: [My initial question concerning the general paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641831/implementation-paradigm-for-efficiently-streaming-zoomable-images-from-machine-v?noredirect=1#comment53153908_32641831)

Comment: For an LWJGL3 tutorial you can have a look at the [tutorials wikipage](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.6.-Tutorial-Index). Especially the "LWJGL3 migration guide" may be useful. For modern OpenGL I'd recommend http://learnopengl.com.

Comment: @javac, I googled high and low yesterday and not one of the tutorials or examples I came across was as useful as that one. It seems everyone is satisfied with the numerous GL11 examples out there. I did eventually get it working yesterday but not using modern OpenGL. With your tutorial there I think I can now make the jump, thanks. (P.S. I'd upvote your comment, but I don't have the rep on this account yet ;p)